# c# counting clicks

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a timer and in 30 minutes I want to count clicks and show it in a textbox. but how? here is timer code:

```
decimal sure = 10;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Enabled = true;
  timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sure--;
  label3.Text = sure.ToString();
  if (sure == 0) 
  {
    timer1.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("Süre doldu");
  }
}
```

Comment: And the specifics of your problem is...?

Comment: Please add if you want to track clicks on a given button or in your app or in OS.

Comment: there is a button1 in button1_Click. every click i want to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your clickCounter at global, and raise your counter++ in Mouse Click Event.
If you do it more specific, you can use Background Worker, to track time.
and use Application.DoEvents() to write remaining to to textBox
Put a button, 2 labels, and a timer. rename labels with lblClickCount and lblRemainingTime

```
private int clickCounter = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickCounter++;
        lblClickCount.Text = clickCounter.ToString();
    }

    decimal sure = 10;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sure--;
        lblRemainingTime.Text = sure.ToString();
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (sure == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Süre doldu. Toplam tiklama sayisi:" + clickCounter.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Serkan bey kod olarak açıklarmısınız? Genel olarak eksik olduğum konu her tıklamada bir işlem yapmak. mesela bir int a=0; olsun. 1. tıklamada a=1, 2. tıklamada a=2 olsun istiyorum.

Comment: you can check now. The code runs what do u want. c/p my code and run

Comment: Nice, your welcome. iyi calismalar dilerim. kod konusunda profilimde email adresim var, daha hizli sonuc alabilirsin birsey yazmak istediginde aklinda bulunsun :)

Comment: çok teşekkürler Serkan Bey. mail adresinizi alıyorum umarım çok rahatsızlık vermem =)
one more last question?
what is  Application.DoEvents(); ? what's its job?

Comment: for ex while in process, you may want update some fields in UI during process, after update command, Application.DoEvents() comes to below, to update your UI changes. This code can work without Application.DoEvents() also

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to reuse buttoN1 to count the clicks but not Start new timer you can add a if around the code you want to protect.

```
bool hasTimerStarted = false;
int numberOfClicks = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!hasTimerStarted)
  {
      button1.Enabled = true;
      timer1.Start();
      hasTimerStarted = true;
  }
  ++numberOfClicks;
}
```

When the timer expires you reset the count and if the timer has started.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    label3.Text = elapsedTime;
    labelClicks.Text = "User clicked " + clicksNo.toString() + "nt times..";

    if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= this.minutes * 60 * 1000) 
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Time elapsed.");
        hasTimerStarted = false;
        numberOfClicks = 0;
    }
}
```